# 2010 HP Desktop Seagate hard disk failure imminent

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

My HP Desktop is giving me the message for my 750GB Seagate hard drive (the one that came with the PC) that Hard Disk Failure is imminent. I have been receiving this message since I reset it to Factory Settings for work. When booting it gives me this on the warning `ST3750528AS:Hard Disk Failure is Imminent.`

If I ignore the message (For instance to grab a work file) and wait for a second it will shut down with no warning. Like hitting the power button. I have a backup drive with the same progs, but is 2000GB. However, when I switch the plugs out the PC boots to the HP logo (the very first thing you see) and no further. I've tried dusting it to no avail (Just the corner of a paper towel).

I received some advice to partition the drive out and reinstall the OS (I assumed it would have had it, being where I got it from), but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look for the HDD manufacturer testing tool and scan the drive. It is most probably at the end of it's life. Make sure to use only a quick test, any sector by sector scans can damage the drive further and your data irrecoverable. Find an external HDD or use a public cloud service to backup your files as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The message you get is from the BIOS which checks the drives [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status. This is probably reporting many reallocated sectors. Usually this means the drive is failing.

Reinstalling the OS or repartitioning does **not** help with that.

You can do clever tricks like scanning the drive, locating groups of failed sectors and partitioning in around them but the drive is still dying. New bad sectors will appear and you will start loosing data.  The only way to deal with this is to not use the drive. (Read: Make sure you have backups, then replace the drive).

I suggest you attempt to make your HP recovery discs if possible.
[See this page](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01867124)

If you cannot make them for any reason you may be able to order a set from HP, the order link can be found on the [drivers page for your specific model](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/) on the HP website.

Comment: That's part of what I'm asking. i had figured I needed to replace the drive. I have a backup, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Any help there?

Comment: First thing to check: Do you have installation media? (A new drive means a new install of the OS on that new clean drive, so get the DVD or pendrives with the OS. And make sure you have the right CoA to reinstall.  But that changes from "my computer is doing this" to "How to I reinstall an OS on a clean desktop".